# El Capitan mysql set datadir

Tags: mysql, osx-elcapitan

Yet another upgrade of OSX (to El Capitan) has fudged MySQL.  The datadir is in a new location.  I'd like to set the datadir back to where my known tables are.

I entered the following into support-files/mysql.server as well as /etc/my.cnf:

```
datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data
```

Unloaded and re-loaded the daemon and it still isn't taking.

Answer (score 1):

From the terminal type:

```
sudo chown -R _mysql:wheel /usr/local/mysql/data
```

and then restart your MySQL daemon.